# how to add childviews dynamically to layout based on screen resolution

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-viewgroup, android-framelayout

I have a layout with screen resolution,

```
public static int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    public static int width =Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

now I want to add multiple childviews to that layout based on its height and width

I know how to add views but wanted to get the count of views that can be added and remaining will be shown in next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just have to calculate it based on the dimensions you have.
So get divide the height of your parent view by the height of the child view and you get the number of views that fit in that parent. Use a floor function to make sure you have a nice rounded number to work with.

Comment: As text is dynamic it can be of any length so for row there may be 3 or 4 child views

Comment: I Guess you would need to measure the items in that case. This should be possible with the onMeasure event.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int, int)
But in that case you would already have to create the child view and remove it if it exceeds the parent height. I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: It is fine to remove views , but can you pls explain it with some code

Comment: This is out of the top of my head, but I think you can do something like this.
`if ((child.getTop() + child.getHeight()) > parent.getHeight) {
 //The view exceeds the height of the parent, remove the view.
 parent.removeView(child);
}`